# Identify the observable that generated the error in flatMap and CatchError

Tags: angular, rxjs

Perhaps I got this wrong but I have two apis to call. API2 can be called if API1 is successful only. But both of them can generate the error at any given time:

```js
this.service.API1(profile['id_token']).pipe(
  flatMap(data => {
    return this.service.API2()
  }),
  catchError(err => {

    return of(false); // want to modify this observale based which generated the error
  })


).subscribe(k => {
    console.log(k)
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err)
  }
)
```

I am catching the errors from both end points when they happen but I couldn't know which one is generating them in a smart way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside you first request `API1` you want to replace `flatMap` to `switchMap` as you're switching to a new api request. Inside the first request you can use the same `catchError` operator and handle error accordingly.

Try something like this:

```js
this.service.API1(profile['id_token']).pipe(
  switchMap(data => {
    return this.service.API2().pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        // do stuff with err from API1 request
        return of(false);
      })
    )
  }),
  catchError(err => {
    // do stuff with err from API2 request
    return of(false);
  })


).subscribe(k => {
    console.log(k)
  },
  err => {
    // you can have this, but unlikely to ever enter. depending on how you handle the errors
    console.log(err)
  }
)
```

[Demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ylfsqg)
[Demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jtwpwm)

Comment: This won't work because any error that occurs in API1 will not actually be hit inside the switchMap. The switchMap will not be called if an error occurs above it in the stream.

Comment: @observingstream, yes it will. depending on you handle the error. OP post doesn't say he needs anything from API1 request for API2 to be fired correctly

Comment: Ok. I have been sounding angry, and I am not. I am trying to understand for my own edification. I have made a stackblitz that shows what I am thinking will happen with your above code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8ddzpw?devtoolsheight=60 Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @observingstream I have to admit I was off with my initial answer, but i'll leave it for posterity, but please see both demos for how I would handle this.

Comment: These totally makes sense. I like you new demos. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

In RxJS, you are dealing with a stream of events. Without some kind of value pushed down the stream that shows which endpoint is actually returning the error, there isn't a way to differentiate between an error coming from one vs the other. You are using `flatMap` which takes multiple streams and merges them into a single stream (see https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

To use your current code, you will need multiple catchErrors to handle an error from each endpoint differently. You can move your `catchError` above the flatMap which will allow you to do something with the first error. You can then pipe off of the second api call inside your `flatMap` which would allow you to catch the error from the second api call.

You can also have the errors that are produced by the server have some kind of differentiating attribute which would allow you filter them through a single `catchError` operator.

Comment: This is more of a comment, also OP is asking to be able to do something with either errors. Assuming `API1` and/or/both `API2` have some sort of error.

Comment: This is not really a comment since it is answering the question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer) and not asking for more information. I will edit it to give more info though.